# Smart quotes stopped working in Edge

Tags: macos, web-browser

I use Microsoft Edge (Version 114.0.1823.58 (Official build) (arm64)) on a Macintosh  (Ventura 13.4.1 (22F82)) and all of a sudden, the realtime (as I’m typing in Gmail and Blogger) substitution of smart quotes has stopped working. Haven’t changed my preferences in Edge or MacOS, and other substitutions — like for instance, a double hyphen (--) with ■ —still work.

Any ideas how to get it working again? (I’ve restarted browser and Mac several times.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the pref in Edge itself? In many apps these can be toggled independently* to any global pref - Edit Menu > Substitutions -

[image]

*In TextEdit, it can be toggled per document.

Comment: Yep, I checked. Still good there. Still no smart quotes …